# Are Catholics literally God eaters?

Tags: catholicism, communion, mass, transubstantiation

According to Catholic doctrine regarding the Eucharist, the objects that look like bread and wine are instead literally Christ's body, blood, soul and divinity.  In which case, when a Catholic eats the object that looks like bread, but is really God, is it correct to say that the Catholic is eating God, within the context of Catholic beliefs regarding the eucharist?

This seems a corollary of calling Mary the mother of God.  When she conceived a little baby that appeared to be a normal human, but was in actual fact God, she was given the title "Mother of God".  Similarly, when a Catholic eats an object that appears to be bread, but is really God, it seems like they are literally eating God, so would be called "eaters of God" in a similar fashion.

UPDATE: This question is different than "[On the Eucharist and Human Digestion?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/64057/on-the-eucharist-and-human-digestion)".  The digestion question is asking about the process, how does the body interact with the Eucharistic substance after it is eaten.  My question is a syntactical question, not about the process, asking whether it is syntactically correct to say that Catholics literally eat God.

Comment: Have you done any research into the Catholic Euchharist?  https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/why-is-the-eucharist-referred-to-as-

Comment: @Lesley yes, I converted to catholicism in 2010, and have read a very large chunk of the Summa and most of the massive catechism.

Comment: @Geremia This question is very different than the one you flag as duplicate.  I prefer you let the community decides.

Comment: What do you mean by "syntactically correct"?

Comment: To know what "eating God" means, you first need to know what is involved in the process of eating. And you also have to distinguish between eating ordinary food and receiving Communion. (Note: We don't see "eat Communion" but "receive Communion" because the processes differ.) Hence, I still don't see how your question differs from "[On the Eucharist and Human Digestion?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/64057/1787)".

Comment: Are you asking if Catholics consume (digest‽) God's divinity after receiving Communion?

Comment: @Geremia no, I know we don't digest God's divinity, since the host turns back into ordinary bread once its form is destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Yes.

There is no ambiguity here. Catholic Doctrine is simple and straightforward in its rites and rituals.

#### Communion is Eating the Christ

During Holy Communion one directly consumes the flesh of the Christ, Lord God:

Mark 14:22

> Jesus took bread, blessed it, broke it, and gave it to them, and said, 'Take; **this is my body**.'

#### Christ is God, and God is Christ

Following from the previous statement, consuming the Flesh of God is directly equivalent to consuming the Flesh of Christ - as God is Christ, Christ is God:

John 10:30

> I and the Father are one.

#### To Disagree or Think Otherwise is Heresy

To take one or even both of the above statements as ambiguous, let alone untrue, is heresy:

Deuteronomy 15:28

> ...if you disobey the Lord your God and do not faithfully keep all his commands and laws that I am giving you today, all these evil things will happen to you...

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it argued from Catholic theology and doctrine. *Sola scriptura* isn't really appropriate.

Comment: Well if there are any other books written by God then I'd be glad to add them as references.

Answer (score 2):

I think Catholics are more precise than you are.  I would rephrase it as **"Catholics are literally *Jesus* eaters"** understanding **Jesus as the *human nature* of God**, a temporal effect and visible presence of God in the material world (for God's realm is spiritual heaven), with God providing Jesus as literally the lamb who takes away the sins of the world (John 1:29) to be eaten the way the Passover lamb is eaten as in the OT: unspotted lamb brought by a family, killed by the priest at the temple altar in Jerusalem, with blood spilled but the meat eaten in a thanksgiving meal with the family, except the Catholic priest did **NOT** do a fresh killing of Jesus, but the Eucharistic meal is a **re-presentation** of the single sacrifice of the Lamb at the Calvary thus placing the congregation of the mass literally around the Last Supper table following Jesus's command to the apostles in the first Last Supper with the priest becoming the "stand-in" for Jesus in the Last Supper.  For a full length lecture about this (to correct any misunderstanding caused by my potential misrepresentation) hear Fr. Dominic Legge's 2021 talk [Entering into Christ's Passion: The Mass as a Sacrifice](https://soundcloud.com/thomisticinstitute/entering-into-christs-passion-the-mass-as-a-sacrifice-fr-dominic-legge-op) which addresses many Protestant objections against Catholic understanding of the Mass.

Thus, it is improper analogy to reduce Jesus to God.  Jesus **IS** God but also **IS** fully human (per Chalcedon), so in the Eucharist as a Paschal thanksgiving meal, we deal with the **human nature** of Jesus, not the eternal Trinitarian God, although since Jesus is the human nature OF GOD, the meal is salvific.

About your phrasing "the objects that look like bread and wine are instead literally Christ's body, blood, soul and divinity" I don't think Catholics would say that the transubstantiated bread and wine "becomes God" or "contains the soul of God" but the ritual is supposed to place us face to face with Jesus literally saying "this is my body" when he lifted the bread in the first Last Supper.  In the Last Supper the apostles certainly did **NOT** perceive the bread to BE divine or soulful !  The right phrasing instead is that the regular bread and wine becomes REAL lamb where now in the 21st century re-presentation of a mass Jesus is FULLY PRESENT (in his human nature) in the transubstantiated bread to become our salvific meal since in the Catholic understanding of the Eucharist it's through Jesus's human nature that the grace of God flows to enter our soul and body in the act of eating.  To say that the transubstantiated bread is divine and soulful would be to objectify God.

Similarly, Mary's title "Mother of God" conceptually means **Mother of the *incarnation* of God**, not the pre-existing being who gave spiritual birth to the spiritual Trinitarian God who existed before the world was created, which would create the chicken-and-egg problem.  Why Mary got the title "Mother of God" is to emphasize that Jesus is not only fully human, but is also God; the context was the controversies regarding the precise nature of Jesus in the 5th century AD.

Comment: I think you’re right - the common phrase is “body, blood, soul, and divinity of Jesus Christ”. So as long as it’s understood it’s both body and divinity you’re in the clear.

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the Theotokos is likewise an imprecise title?  Instead it should be said that Mary is the mother of Jesus, just like you state Catholics are eaters of Jesus?

Comment: @yters It's not imprecise; every title can have a built-in correct **range of meaning** that we should responsibly retrieve from the minds of the framer, in this case from around 5th century (see *Wikipedia*), just with any other key philosophical term such as "natural law" whose meaning has evolved over the centuries.  I think Catholics, Eastern Orthodox and magisterial Protestants alike are looking to that period as the source of meaning, and we today should do the same as a matter of proper exegesis.

Comment: As CCC 469 states: There is no “human Jesus” without “Jesus, God”.

Comment: In general, your answer doesn't really match up with what I've read in the Summa nor the Catechism.  My understanding is we Catholics believe the bread literally turns into God, and is no longer bread.  The substance in "transubstantiation" is the essence of what the object is, and at time T1 the substance is "bread" and at time T2 after the priest performs the ritual it is now "God".  Are you yourself Catholic and answering from the Catholic perspective, or a non-Catholic answering from what you think Catholics believe?

Comment: @yters I **am** answering from the Catholic perspective, and I can distinguish clearly in my mind what I read about the Lutheran church & the Anglican church, the confessional reformed position (the church I was brought up), the baptist reformed position (my wife's church) and ; so 5 different views of various levels of "real presence" in the Eucharist from most real to not real at all (Baptist).  I read a lot of Catholic literature; the language they use is that of Jesus / Christ, not God, when talking about transubstantiation.

Comment: @yters In Catholic (as well as Lutheran, Anglican, and Confessional Reformed), "God" refers to the Trinitarian eternal being outside time and space.  "Jesus / Christ" refers to the "incarnation" of this spiritual God (as Logos, the 2nd person) by **adding** (not becoming) a human nature, the God-man we call Jesus / Christ.  Jesus is the one giving his flesh, so it makes sense to use the same language when talking about transubstantiation.

Comment: @yters It's the **added** nature that we consume, but because of the intermingling of human + divine properties (although unconfused), there is divinity in the bread, since what we eat (Jesus's body) is a divine body.  Otherwise it's cannibalism.  Conceptually though, we need to distinguish between incarnated God and God, thus Christian theologies never say we eat God.  Per Scripture it also makes sense: Jesus is the Lamb that God provides, we eat Jesus as we eat Lamb who takes away our sin; it is once-for-all lamb since the Lamb is divine.

Comment: @yters Another Biblical language that is imported into Christian theologies in all 3 Trinitarian branches (Catholic, Eastern Orthodox, and Protestants), is "Son of God" refers to the Eternal Logos (2nd person of the Trinity), while "Son of Man" refers to the added human nature, Jesus / Christ.  I hope that helps.